# Firebase Image Upload to Storage .put() crashes. React, Capacitor, iOS. Works every time on web. Work ~25% on device iOS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-storage, capacitor

I have a react web app using Ionic Capacitor to run on iOS using Firebase Firestore and storage.

Firestore works perfectly. However having trouble with uploading images to the storage. Testing in Chrome and Safari on web works perfectly.

Testing on device it will fail 3 out of 4 times on the .put() giving this error in xCode console. And it won't run the error catch function when it does fail.

```
2020-05-25 18:42:52.176087+0100 ABCD [581:61537] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <NSError: 0x281285260; domain: RBSAssertionErrorDomain; code: 2; reason: "Client is missing required entitlement"> {
    userInfo = {
        RBSAssertionAttribute = <RBSLegacyAttribute: 0x100457950; requestedReason: FinishTaskUnbounded; reason: FinishTaskUnbounded; flags: PreventTaskSuspend>;
    }
    }
    2020-05-25 18:42:52.176124+0100 ABCD [581:61537] [ProcessSuspension]  0x10a4d71d8 - ProcessAssertion() PID 581 Unable to acquire assertion for process with PID 584
    2020-05-25 18:42:52.176171+0100 ABCD [581:55904] [ProcessSuspension] 0x10a4d71d8 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
    2020-05-25 18:42:52.177100+0100 ABCD [581:61537] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <NSError: 0x281289260; domain: RBSAssertionErrorDomain; code: 2; reason: "Client is missing required entitlement"> {
        userInfo = {
            RBSAssertionAttribute = <RBSLegacyAttribute: 0x10056c9f0; requestedReason: FinishTaskUnbounded; reason: FinishTaskUnbounded; flags: PreventTaskSuspend>;
        }
        }
        2020-05-25 18:42:52.177132+0100 ABCD [581:61537] [ProcessSuspension]  0x10a4d7200 - ProcessAssertion() PID 581 Unable to acquire assertion for process with PID 581
        2020-05-25 18:42:52.177180+0100 ABCD [581:55904] [ProcessSuspension] 0x10a4d7200 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
```

If it successfully uploads the image it will still give this error message.

Does anyone know what causes this error, and why this will still work some of the time?

Let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: I have no idea but when googling using the "Client is missing required entitlement" message you have in the logs you show, it looks like there is some authorization you should add so your app can access storage (or something similar). From what I can tell, Apple calls it Entitlement https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements

If this resource does not help, have you tried digging on Ionic side? I also saw someone mentioning this happen since iOS 11+

Comment: I am struggling with the same issue is there a specific entitlement required for apple that needs to be added? Were you able to find a solution to this problem?